How to interface MQ135 with raspberry pi 4?
So last time i was trying to interface MQ135 AIR QUALITY SENSOR using raspberry pi 4 but there is this analog out pin which is creating a problem as raspberry pi don't accept any analog signal. So now what should i do? should i use raspberry pi with ADC or arduino ? but our professor rejected the idea of using the arduino? so is their any other alternatives? or any other method ??
i am trying get data from the MQ135 about the air quality and display it on oled display screen, but couldn't, please help me with the python libraries to be used too.
